# Kafka & debezium Connector Automatic creation of schemas if the table is empty

Tags: apache-kafka, debezium, opensearch

I am working with Kafka & the debezium connector. The whole thing is consumed by OpenSearch. But when I create a new table and tell OpenSearch the new topic, an error occurs if there is no data in the underlying table yet. Only when data is available in the table does the connector create the schema. Is it possible to get the debezium connector to create schemas even if there is no data in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there's no data, then there's no schema to infer... But there shouldn't be any error since the Connector has nothing to do when there's no data

You're more than welcome to pre-create schemas you need. That'll also prevent unexpected errors with auto created schemas